# How to change value of property inside data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Currently, my sample HTML code look like this:

```
<div class="jbar" data-init="jbar" data-jbar='{
    "message" : "Test",
    "state"   : "open"
}'></div>
```

How can I change the `state` value to `closed` in this case?

Comment: Well, stored as it is, it is a string, not an object.  You'd have to parse it, then alter it, then store it again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It'd be great if you can give me an example how to do it or is there any easier way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jquery would look something like

```
var t=JSON.parse($('.jbar').attr('data-jbar'));
//or  JSON.parse($('.jbar').data('jbar'));
t.state='closed';
$('.jbar').attr('data-jbar',JSON.stringify(t));
//or      .data('jbar',JSON.stringify(t));
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried your solution but it's still showing `open`. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bb9vnzw2/

Comment: @VuiLaChinh Your fiddle doesn't have the `$('.jbar').attr('data-jbar',JSON.stringify(t));` part.

Comment: here is a fiddle setting the `attr` http://jsfiddle.net/bb9vnzw2/3/ like @Jason_P mentioned